# Traversing all nodes in an XML file with VBScript

Tags: xml, vbscript, msxml, xmldom

I have written a VBScript which is supposed to tranverse all nodes in an XML file, irrespective of the depth of the tree. This it does well *except* that the node names for the those nodes which are 2 or more levels deep are not displayed. I need the node names as well as the values so that I have name/value pairs for further processing by other programs. Can anyone please help me in getting the missing node names displayed.

Below is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/vbscript">
Set xmlDoc=CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.async="false"
xmlDoc.load("test.xml")
Dim objDocElem, strNode, strSubNode, xmlnn, xmlnv, xmlnc, xmldd, xmlfd, xmlfv

Set n_firstchild = xmldoc.documentElement.firstChild
Set p_node = n_firstchild.parentNode
Set pn_attribs = p_node.attributes
For Each pnAttr in pn_attribs
   xmlfd = xmlfd & pnAttr.name & chr(9)
   xmlfv = xmlfv & pnAttr.value & chr(9)
Next 

Set objDocElem=xmlDoc.documentElement

Set y = objDocElem.childNodes
i=0
Do While i < y.length 
If y(i).nodeType <> 3 Then
  If Isnull(y(i).childNodes(0).nodeValue) Then
     xmlnv = xmlnv & "Category" & chr(9)
  Else
     xmlnv = xmlnv & y(i).childNodes(0).nodeValue & chr(9)
  End If
  xmlnn = xmlnn & y(i).nodeName & chr(9)
  xmlnc = xmlnc + 1
  z=0
  Do While z < y(i).childNodes.length
    If y(i).childNodes(z).nodeType <> 3 Then
       xmlnc = xmlnc + 1
       xmlnn = xmlnn & y(i).childNodes(z).nodeName & chr(9)
       xmlnv = xmlnv & y(i).childNodes(z).text & chr(9)
    End If
    z=z+1
  Loop
End If
i=i+1  
Loop

document.write("form details: " & xmlfd & "<br />")
document.write("form values: " & xmlfv & "<br /><br />")
document.write("node names: " & xmlnn & "<br />")
document.write("node values: " & xmlnv & "<br />")
document.write("<br />node count: " & xmlnc & "<br />")

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<form penid="AJX-AAE-CRB-7P" submitted="2009-09-10 14:57:07" updated="2009-09-10 15:05:22" finalised="2009-09-10 15:59:48">
  <Forename>Russell</Forename>
  <Surname>Kilby</Surname>
  <HouseNumber>248</HouseNumber>
  <Letter>GRG</Letter>
  <Products>
    <WinSoftware>Product One</WinSoftware>
    <MacSoftware>Product Two</MacSoftware>        
    <LnxSoftware>Product Three</LnxSoftware>
    <Generic>
        <Product1>Speedo</Product1>
        <Product2>Switches</Product2>
        <Product3>BIOS</Product3>
        <TestOne>
            <Panel1>Front</Panel1>
            <Panel2>Back</Panel2>
            <Panel3>Middle</Panel3>
        </TestOne>
    </Generic>
    <Hardware>Fender</Hardware>
  </Products>
  <HouseName>Just Tea House</HouseName>
  <PostCode>B87 7DF</PostCode>
  <Insurer>ABC Cars</Insurer>
  <PolicyNumber>FDA 8D3JD7K</PolicyNumber>
  <Make>Ford</Make>
  <VehicleReg>EX51 CBA</VehicleReg>
  <DescriptionOfDamage>Big smash on the from</DescriptionOfDamage>
  <Estimate>1300</Estimate>
  <AlertManager>Yes</AlertManager>
</form>
```

Comment: It would help massively if you posted the desired output so we don't have to imagine what it is your are expecting and we can largely ignore your code and show how you should've done it.

Answer (score 8):

Please, try this:

```
set nodes = xmlDoc.selectNodes("//*")    
for i = 0 to nodes.length
    document.write(nodes(i).nodeName & " - " & nodes(i).text & "<br />")
next
```

Comment: Thanks Rubens. That helped me enormously. All I needed was a nudge in the right direction. So much more constructive than the fatuous comments of by AnthonyWJones.

Comment: Somehow he got a point: you really should learn about XPath. XML gets even more funnier when you drop DOM navigation and start jumping directly on your data. XPath seems scary at first, but in two days that feeling go away =)

Comment: ^two days^two years .   But if you want to learn xpath, try http://xpathvisualizer.codeplex.com (Windows only)

Comment: The For Loop should be `for i = 0 to nodes.length - 1`